# Gathering information from point to nearest polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, fields-attributes, proximity

I am using QGIS and would like to know what is the nearest vegetation type from a point (animal location) to nearest polygon. What tool I should use?

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html google for 'nearest neighbor analysis' in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Open attribute table and field calculator in animal point layer.
Create new field with name of your choice, type `"text"`

use expression:

```
array_to_string(overlay_nearest('name_of_your_polygon_layer', "name_of_field_where_vegetation_type_is_stored"))
```

In animal layer you will have new field where nearest vegetation type is stored.